# Edit historical git merge titles

Tags: git, github, version-control

Basically, I have a portfolio on git, however I recently changed my username. I found a really helpful bash script to change commit users to my new username, but the merge of my branches still includes my old username, for example:

Merge pull request #27 from OLD-USER-NAME/branch-name

I'd like to edit OLD-USER-NAME to my current username. Obviously clicking the link takes you to my repo which is fine, but I want it to be consistent, and I'd like to keep my commit history so anybody looking at my portfolio can see my commit history.

The merge pull request's dont show in the commit history using git's rebase feature.

Is there any way of doing this?

Many thanks!

For reference, the script I used to rename is:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Comment: The `git filter-branch` command *can* do this (see the `--msg-filter`) but you probably should consider using the newfangled `git filter-repo`. Both commands can do the entire job in a single pass, but filter-repo is supposed to be much easier to use (though I have not used it yet myself).

Comment: @torek thank you for the advice, I'll take a look at that and see if I can work something out!